# XSLT How to grab the value of the following first

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to XSLT.
I have an XML like this:

```
<root>
    <story>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <strongp>
            <color>Attention</color>
            SomeText
        </strongp>
        <p>
            Text of interest1
            <a id="1234-3457">here</a>
        </p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <h5>Header H5</h5>
        <strongp>
            <color>Attention</color>
            SomeText
        </strongp>
        <p>
            Text of interest2
            <a id="8909-3457">here</a>
        </p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <inline/>
    </story>
</root>
```

And here's xsl I'm using to transform `<strongp>` into another complex element `<remark>`

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="strongp/color" />
    <xsl:template match="strongp[color][contains(.,'Attention')]">
        <remark>
            <remarkheader>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
            </remarkheader>
            <remarktext>
                <xsl:for-each select=".">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(following-sibling::p[1])"/>
                 </xsl:for-each></remarktext>
        </remark>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<root>
        <story>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <remark>
                <remarkheader>Attention SomeText</remarkheader>
                <remarktext>Text of interest1 here</remarktext>
            </remark>
            <p>
                Text of interest
                <a id="1234-3457">here</a>
            </p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <h5>Header H5</h5>
            <remark>
                <remarkheader>Attention SomeText</remarkheader>
                <remarktext>Text of interest2 here</remarktext>
            </remark>
            <p>
                Text of interest
                <a id="8909-3457">here</a>
            </p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <inline/>
        </story>
    </root>
```

In the output I get the value of following first `<p>`. But I need to grab the value of the first `<p>`with **all its markup**, attributes inside child elements. And then that first `<p>`needs to be deleted. How do I get that markup and remove that 1st `<p>` in result?
The result needed:

```
<root>
    <story>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <remark>
            <remarkheader>Attention SomeText</remarkheader>
            <remarktext>Text of interest1 <a id="1234-3457">here</a></remarktext>
        </remark>   
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <h5>Header H5</h5>
        <remark>
            <remarkheader>Attention SomeText</remarkheader>
            <remarktext>Text of interest2 <a id="8909-3457">here</a></remarktext>
        </remark>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <inline/>
    </story>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another template to skip processing the `<p>` elements following `<strongp>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="strongp/color" />
<xsl:template match="p[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::strongp][color][contains(.,'Attention')]]"/>
<xsl:template match="strongp[color][contains(.,'Attention')]">
    <remark>
        <remarkheader>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        </remarkheader>
        <remarktext>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::p[1]/node()"/>
        </remarktext>
    </remark>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```